# how to display html page inside asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, html

I have articles written formatted in html, and I would like to display it inside my asp.net page.

Please help

Comment: do you have examples of how you're displaying the articles now? What's it *not* doing?

Comment: i have tried to read htm file with simple text reader (it creates one big string), and then to assign that string to part of my page. but it looks like html tags are lost during text reading operation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<iframe src="simple.html" border="0" frameborder="0" height="600" width="800"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use it as is.

If you place HTML in an `aspx` page, it will remain unchanged.

---

Seeing as you want to display several HTML pages within another, you can use html [FRAMEs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html).

Comment: But i am using multilanguge page, and those articles are detached from my asp.net page because I display it according to chosen language? Thanks

Comment: ok i understand that. but i have default.aspx and englisharticle.html, and frencharticle.html. I want to display those html files in one part of aspx page. is there simething like: literal1.text=readhtml(englisharticle.html);

Answer (score 0):

You can display them inside an [`iframe`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp).

Comment: does anybody know what is asp.net control which does the same like iframe

Comment: ok i found out. i should have been using id tag for i frame, and then addattribute src dynamicly. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Is this an entire Html page - in which case is there a need for the aspx page at all.
Or is this just formatting tags, e.g. `<b>bold heading</b>` ?